# Perl, execute bash command with pipe

Tags: bash, perl

Sorry if my English is bad.

I have a bash command:

```
convert somefile1.png somefile2.png -resize '200x200!' MIFF:- | compare -metric AE -fuzz '5%' - null:-
```

That command returns number, how can I get this value in my perl script?

My code:

```
my $s_command = 
    "convert " . $s_img1_path . " " .  
    $s_img2_path . " -resize '" . 
    $N_IMAGEMAGICK_IMG_SIZE . "x" . $N_IMAGEMAGICK_IMG_SIZE . 
    "!' MIFF:- | compare -metric AE -fuzz '5%' - null:-";

my $s_out = `$s_command`;
```

But I can't get the return value in $s_out. Moreover, this value goes to stdout itself, why?

Comment: `my $com = 'find ./parse_CDATA -type f'; 
my @files = \`$com\`;
chomp @files;` You can use pipes like this in perl !!

Comment: Can I just point out that your English is impressively fluent. If you're using "moreover" correctly, you're way ahead of most native speakers :-)

Comment: Are you sure that the output goes to STDOUT? I ran a sample script with exactly the same structure as yours and it worked as you want it to

Comment: @toolic, @yonyon100 Thanks a lot, both of you are right, output of that command goes to STDERR. I just add `2>&1` in the end of that command and get that value. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Dave Cross, Thanks, but I dont't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $cmd = "grep strict test.pl -n|cut -c1-12";
my $result = `$cmd`;
print $result;
```

The output to STDOUT was as expected (I ran the grep on this code, actually):

```
2:use strict
4:my $cmd =
```

When I commented out the `print` line, there was no output to STDOUT.
Maybe the problem has something to do with STDERR, you should check that.